# Intellij, download sources, how to find usage and so on

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I am using Intellij in a Java environment. Occasionally I like to navigate to the source code of the libraries I use and "download sources" which works fine.

However, I'd like it to behave more as if I had the sources myself. Intellij downloads them, but they can't not be used to for instance "Find Usage of a method". For that you actually have to download the sources and include them to your project.

Is there a way to be able to "Find usages" for downloaded sources?

If not, then this would be pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

By default, "Find Usages" is set to "Project Files" scope. To change this, follow these steps.

Click on the "Find" tab. It's in the bottom left corner by default. If it's not visible, perform a "Find Usages" or any other Find operation.

From there, click on the "Settings" button:

[image: Find Settings Dialog Button]

Then, select the desired scope. You probably want "Project and Libraries".

[image]